# Can lights flicker when ceiling fan is switched on and off

Tags: electrical

In my living room I have two 3-way switches that control the light of the ceiling fan, a single-pole that controls the fan, and a single-pole that controls two can lights above my fireplace. I noticed yesterday that the can lights flicker ever so slightly when the single-pole to the fan is toggled on and off.

My first inclination was a loose neutral. I checked all of the connected neutrals and they are all combined well and tight in the wire nuts. The ceiling fan is probably around 20 years old.

Is it possible this is a faulty fan, or would my next step be to replace the single-pole switch operating the fan?

Comment: What type are the light bulbs?  LEDs are more prone to electrical changes than other types.  Did you check the hots also?  A circuit is a hot and neutral wire, either can have problems.  Unless the switch feels funny, replacement might not help, it will not hurt either.

Comment: Thank you, @crip659 - it appears that LED bulbs are most likely my problem. I did check the hots as well and everything is very well connected.

Comment: Can still be a problem with the fan, or the LED drivers wearing/burning out.  LEDs are more sensitive, so they might show a problem sooner with the circuit or they just might be reacting to minor normal changes in the circuit.